# Is this style of self reference acceptable or anti-pattern?

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I recently discovered through trial and error that I can create modules (I'm working with React, so this is ES6) that refer to themselves like this and they appear to work just fine (see the use of 'CollectionManger' inside of 'CollectionManager'):

```js
export const CollectionManager = {
  collections: [],

  createCollection: () => {
      let collection = {id: Math.random()};
      collection.doSomething = () => {
        console.log(`Doing: ${collection.id}`);
      };
      CollectionManager.collections.push(collection);
    }
  }
};
```

I really like this syntax for the particular case where I want an object that manages instances of itself. This seems more straightforward and less convoluted than other ways of doing self-reference I've seen (a getter/setter, or a class, or even 'this.') But I've never seen this pattern before and I don't know if that's because it's somewhat new or if I just stumbled on some junk that happens to appear to work but is somehow a Very Bad Idea.

Q: Is this acceptable? If not, why?

Comment: It works but I personally don't see why you'd do that over having a non-arrow method and using `this`

Comment: It's just an ordinary closure.